# Calculating a linear trend line for every row of a table in R

Tags: r, regression, trendline

is it somehow possible to conduct a linear regression for every single row of a data frame without using a loop? The output (intercept + slope) of the trend line should be added to the original data frame as new columns.

To make my intention more clearly, I have prepared a very small data example:

```
day1 <- c(1,3,1)
day2 <- c(2,2,1)
day3 <- c(3,1,5)
output.intercept <- c(0,4,-1.66667)
output.slope <- c(1,-1,2)
data <- data.frame(day1,day2,day3,output.intercept,output.slope)
```

Input variables are day1-3; let's say those are the sales for different shops on 3 consecutive days. What I want to do is to calculate a linear trend line for the 3 rows and add the output parameters to the origin table (see output.intercept + output.slope) as new columns.

The solution should be very efficient in terms of calculation time since the real data frame has many 100k's of rows.

Best, Christoph

Comment: What is the response variable?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein The responses are show, the covariate is implied to be `1:3` (in this case), `seq_len(nrow(dat))` in the more general case.

Answer (score 5):

```
design.mat <- cbind(1,1:3)
response.mat <- t(data[,1:3])

reg <- lm.fit(design.mat, response.mat)$coefficients
data <- cbind(data, t(reg))
#  day1 day2 day3 output.intercept output.slope        x1 x2
#1    1    2    3          0.00000            1  0.000000  1
#2    3    2    1          4.00000           -1  4.000000 -1
#3    1    1    5         -1.66667            2 -1.666667  2
```

However, if you have massive data, it might be necessary to loop due to memory restrictions. If that's the case I would use a long format data.table and use the package's `by` syntax to loop.

Comment: Woow, works perfect. 
Thx a lot! I will try it later with the big data set.

What is exaclty "design.mat" for? To simulate x-values?

Comment: If you don't know what a design matrix is, you should study a textbook on regression.

Comment: Thanks again, the solution works perfect even with big data. However one problem occurs when "data" contains missing data points in form of NAs. ("Error in lm.fit(design.mat, response.mat) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'")

Is there any way to deal with the problem of some missing data points? I've already tried to include the na.exclude function into the lm.fit statement but it does not work in this case.

Comment: You need to remove lines containing `NA` values from the design and response matrix before using `lm.fit`. That's one of the many things `lm` conveniently does for you, but that in sum cost a lot of performance.

Comment: Unfortunately removing lines containing NA is not an option, at least in one special case since in one data table of mine almost every column contains NA's. Isn't there another possibility to conduct the regression only on available data and "simply" not considering values with NA? Otherwise I will somehow have to manipulate my origin data file beforehand.

Comment: Think about what you are asking for.

Comment: is it possible to generate the p value for each row? the way you have done

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to implement it yourself if you use a low-level function like `lm.fit` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data,

```
day1 <- c(1,3,1)
day2 <- c(2,2,1)
day3 <- c(3,1,5)
output.intercept <- c(0,4,-1.66667)
output.slope <- c(1,-1,2)
dat <- data.frame(day1,day2,day3)
```

I think you want something like this:

```
fits <- lm.fit(cbind(1, seq_len(nrow(dat))), t(dat))
t(coef(fits))
```

Which gives

```
R> t(coef(fits))
         x1 x2
[1,]  0.000  1
[2,]  4.000 -1
[3,] -1.667  2
```

These can be added to `dat` like so

```
dat <- cbind(dat, t(coef(fits)))
names(dat)[-(1:3)] <- c("Intercept","Slope")

R> dat
  day1 day2 day3 Intercept Slope
1    1    2    3     0.000     1
2    3    2    1     4.000    -1
3    1    1    5    -1.667     2
```

It would perhaps be easier to store the data the other way, with columns as time series, rather than rows, if you have any control over the way the data are arranged initially as it would avoid having to transpose a large matrix when fitting via `lm.fit()`. Ideally, you;d want the data arranged like this initially:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
day1    1    3    1
day2    2    2    1
day3    3    1    5
```

I.e. the rows as the time points rather than individual series as you have them now. This is because of the way R expects data to be arranged. Note we have to transpose your `dat` in the `lm.fit()` call which will entail a copy of a large object. Hence if you can control how these data are arranged/supplied before they get into R, that would help for the large problem.

`lm.fit()` is used as that is the underlying, lean code used by `lm()` but we avoid the complexities of parsing the formula and creating model matrices. If you want more efficient, you might have to look to doing the QR decomposition yourself (the code is in `lm.fit()` to do this) as there are a few things `lm.fit()` does as sanity checks that you might be able to do away with if you are certain your data won't lead to singular matrices etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realise I have still sooo much to learn in R, even the basic things. And thankn you for the hint regarding the data structure. I have control over the data arrangement since I've done some data prepartion in R beforehand. I thought I would be more efficient this way, since my real data file contains 600k rows and only 100 columns.

Comment: One note: I assume the statement "fits <- lm.fit(cbind(1, seq_len(nrow(dat))), t(dat))" should be adjusted to "fits <- lm.fit(cbind(1, seq_len(ncol(dat))), t(dat))". Or am I wrong? It worked in the example because ncol(dat) = nrow(dat).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as OP.  This solution will work on data with NAs.  All of the previous answers generate an error for me in this case:

```
slp = function(x) {
  y = t(x)
  y = y[!is.na(y)]
  len = length(y):1
  b = cov(y,len)/var(len)
  return(b)}

reg_slp <- apply(data,1,slp)
```

Only gets the slope, but the intercept could be easily added.  I doubt this is particularly efficient, but it was effective in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this?

```
day1 <- c(1,3,1)
day2 <- c(2,2,1)
day3 <- c(3,1,5)
data <- data.frame(day1,day2,day3)
y<-1:3

reg<-apply(data,1,function(x) lm(as.numeric(x)~y))
data[,c("intercept","slope")]<-rbind(reg[[1]]$coef,reg[[2]]$coef,reg[[3]]$coef)
```

Comment: That is correct, but not efficient. Note that `lm()` has to parse the formula `nrow(dat)` times, which is quick if you are doing 3 times, slow if you are doing in 100K times. Also, this misses a feature of `lm()` in that it accepts a matrix response. So you don't need the `apply()` or loop here at all; you can fit all the series in a single `lm()` call: `lm(t(data[, 1:3]) ~ I(1:3))`. However, you don't want to be parsing a formula and generating the model.frame and model.matrix plus all the extra guff `lm()` gives you if you want to be efficient. Use `lm.fit()` for that for an improvement.