# Generating a new regression equation for every row of a table in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am newer to R and found the post in the link below, which is similar to what I am trying to accomplish.

[Calculating a linear trend line for every row of a table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783871/calculating-a-linear-trend-line-for-every-row-of-a-table-in-r)

What I would like to do is the same thing but create a new regression equation for each row for two different tables.

Below is some example data.

```
Closesday1 <- c(2,6,10)
Closedays2 <- c(3,7,15)
Closedays3 <- c(5,8,20)

dataY<-data.frame(Closesday1,Closedays2,Closedays3)
Dep<-t(dataY)


Valuesday1 <- c(4,6,8)
Valuesday2 <- c(5,8,11)
Valuesday3 <- c(7,9,14)
dataX<-data.frame(Valuesday1,Valuesday2,Valuesday3)
Ind<-t(dataX)
```

For Dep we get:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
Closesday1    2    6   10
Closedays2    3    7   15
Closedays3    5    8   20
```

For Ind we get:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
Valuesday1    4    6    8
Valuesday2    5    8   11
Valuesday3    7    9   14
```

What I would like to do is create a regression equation (linear to start) for variable 1,2 and 3 taking closesday 1 values and regressing against Valuesday 1 for variables 1,2 and 3 (so 2,6,10 against 4,6,8). A new regression equation would be calculated for closesday2 vs valuesday2 and another for closesday3 vs valuesday3 etc...  I would then like to have the output included in a new table with columns added for intercept and slope for each.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine these steps into one to be more efficient:

```
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(seq(nrow(Dep)), function(x) coeffs <- lm(Dep[x, ] ~ Ind[x, ])$coefficients)))
```

To get coefficients and fitted values into a single data frame, try this:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(Dep)), function(x) {fit <- lm(Dep[x, ] ~ Ind[x, ]); c(fit$coefficients, fit$fitted.values, `3` = rep(NA, (ncol(Dep) - length(fit$fitted.values))))}))

df
     (Intercept) Ind[x, ]        1        2        3
[1,]   -6.000000 2.000000 2.000000 6.000000       NA
[2,]   -3.666667 1.333333 3.000000 7.000000       NA
[3,]  -10.923077 2.192308 4.423077 8.807692 19.76923
```

Note that NA's in each row create missing fitted values. I am simply filling the last of them with NA's in the resulting row.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for the response! Much appreciated.

Comment: .You can combine the second sapply into first one to increase efficiency. I split it up that way to show what goes on at each step. Edited the answer to also show that case.

Comment: Than you very much. Do you know how to output the fitted values as well?

Comment: Repalce `$coefficients` in that line with `$fitted.values`. If you want both in a single table, you will need to save output of `lm` to a variable - let us say `fit` - and return `c(fit$coefficients, fit$fitted.values)`.

Comment: Thank you! One additional problem I seem to be running into is if there is 1 column with NA values for a certain number of rows but takes on a value eventually. Say we have the below:  

Valuesday1 <- c(4,6,NA)
Valuesday2 <- c(5,8,NA)
Valuesday3 <- c(7,9,14)

Closesday1 <- c(2,6,NA)
Closedays2 <- c(3,7,NA)
Closedays3 <- c(5,8,20)

Running model is ok, but I get an error when trying to output the coefficients. Incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: What is the problem you see in that case?

Comment: Your code gets cut off too...so I can't see what you posted completely. Use back ticks to format code in comments.

Comment: The below changes are for the original code:

`Valuesday1 <- c(4,6,NA)`
 `Valuesday2 <- c(5,8,NA)`
 `Valuesday3 <- c(7,9,14)`

`Closesday1 <- c(2,6,NA)`
`Closedays2 <- c(3,7,NA)`
`Closedays3 <- c(5,8,20)`

Comment: So, I understand, what is the problem you see? The code runs fine and produces proper output with the NAs at least from what I can see.

Comment: Interesting, when I run `df['coefficients', ]` I get the message: Error in df["coefficients", ] : incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: Ah...just use that last line (combined) version. Sorry, there is an error in the original split step code, which does generate this error. Editing.

Comment: ok thanks! That seems to work. is there something similar for fitted values?

`df <- data.frame(t(sapply(seq(nrow(Dep)), function(x) fitted.values <- lm(Dep[x, ] ~ Ind[x, ])$fitted.values)))`

That seems to work ok, but am trying to set up the output similar to the coefficients. With a new row for each regression calculation. The output from that look to list them all on the same row.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this need.